# Wordpress plugin compatibility explaination when wordpress releases its new version (theoretical)

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org, wordpress-version

Recently i updated my `wordpress` to its latest `version 3.4.1` and noticed that few of my plugins are only compatible upto 3.3 although they are working correctly for my site even with the latest version.

So does that means that i need to disable those plugins and look for the alternatives and these plugins are no more `SAFE` to use or it is something else( i downloaded all plugins from `wordpress.org` ONLY) .

Need a better clarification over this and let me know if some concept i m missing with the up gradation :) . Detailed answer is really appreciated and i will do my part then :)

Comment: Normally, I'm more worried with plugins that show, say, 3.1 compatibility... Those I test, as toscho points out, more thoroughly.

Comment: @brasofilo plz check my comment on toscho post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility shows just the latest version the plugin was tested on. If WordPress didn’t change the API the plugin will continue working and you don’t have to worry.

[Test it.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57436/73) There is no other way to be sure.

Comment: so is thr any plugin that can check vulnerability in plugin  files??

Comment: That’s a different question. In short: no, not really. There are unlimited ways how a plugin can be vulnerable, impossible to test that automatically. There _are_ plugins claiming to find security holes. They are (in my opinion) snake oil.